# Revolution Slider - stop scroll page if slider is full height

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, frontend, revolution-slider

I want to get some effect in the Revolution Slider. I get tired of it for a few days and I need help.

My example slider on the site: http://projektybagelo.serwerbagelo.pl/fitdostawcy/testowa/

The effect I want to get:

When we go down to the bottom of the slider, scrolling the page should stop. Then scrolling through all the slides (Mouse Scroll Navigation is on) and when we move to the last slide, scrolling the page must start working again.

Scrolling the slide must begin when we only see a full slide at 100% of the page height.

When scrolling up is to be the opposite effect - when we reach the top of the slider, scrolling the page must stop, scroll through all the slides and when we are on the first slide, scrolling the page must work again.

Can anyone help me? I can even pay.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a programmer for hire site - if you plan to solve your problem yourself, and just need help, then your question should include what you've tried so far / the relevant code you are working off of. If you're *not* planning to solve the problem yourself, you'll have better luck on a different site :)